# How do I find community wikis?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I'm curious to see what topics the wikis cover, but I don't know how to find/locate them. I tried doing a tag search for "community-wiki" but it didn't show up anything.

Comment: It's worth noting that community wikification is mostly a historical artifact at this point. While you still have the option to make certain posts community wiki, there's almost never any reason to do so.

Comment: Would the following question be appropriate for community wiki: "How does one derive Lagrange's equation from D'Alembert's principle"? (It would be nice to have some textbook style derivations filed in with additional comments and insights to make it easier to digest.)

Comment: No, it would not. As I said, there's pretty much never any reason to make a post community wiki. However, if you've looked at textbooks and/or other resources and there's something that confuses you about those derivations, you could certainly ask about that here.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the *tag wikis* (which are different)?

"Community wiki" means a state of a post (question or answer) that makes it easier for other users to edit. To search for wiki posts [use the `wiki:1` search modifier](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/search).

"Tag wikis" are  special posts that are attached to particular tags. To access them, click on a tag (either under a question, in the sidebar, or in the "TAGS" tab) and then select the link in the little box at the top.[image]

Comment: I think I meant community wikis. Actual answers to questions that have been handed over to the community. I want to see what sort of questions they deal with.

Comment: Ah. Edited to include a link to the advance search tips.